# Configuration file for command-line options

Tags: agda

I'd like all modules in my Agda library to be compiled with the `--prop` [command-line option](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/command-line-options.html). Is there some configuration file where I can put default options for my library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `flags:` field in the library's `.agda-lib`.
The test case for the feature is precisely `--prop`: https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/ebf922e06c3d1e86ae3cd4cc99cbe9ac8bc5648a/test/Succeed/default-flags/lib.agda-lib

It's all in the manual: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2/tools/package-system.html#library-files